# Sidebar title does not wrap properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying out the [Simple Sidebar Demo](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/) . However after changing the sidebar title it messes up:

[image: Screenshot of problem]

How do I fix it so that:

- The menu items are pushed down instead of being overwritten
- There is not all that whitespace between the two rows of the title

Here is a cut down version of the demo that still shows the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Simple Sidebar - Start Bootstrap Template</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        This title does not appear to word-wrap properly
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Dashboard</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Shortcuts</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Overview</a> </li>
        </div>
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-lg-12"> Bla bla
        </div> </div> </div> </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is `simple-sidebar.css`:

```
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not to seem rude, as that is not my intention at all, but as a person with very high rep, please remember that we require people to include a minimal example. Your code includes plenty of unnecessary information (like the head, doctype, js, other content, etc.) that makes it harder to answer. As a person with high reputation, you are an example for lower rep users, who may end up doing this same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure which parts of the CSS are relevant to the problem. Have reduced the HTML some more.

Comment: That's good. I just wanted to make sure you were aware that a lot of that wasn't relevant. Again I didn't want to come off as rude at all; I just want this site to be the best it can be :)

Comment: I have adjusted my answer a lot. See if that helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixing the Wrapping:

You are setting two properties here:

`line-height` and `text-indent`:

```
.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

[Removing those two properties here makes the text wrap properly](http://jsfiddle.net/u5w72jep/1/).

*Perhaps you are looking for `margin-left` to push the entire element, and not just the first line?*

---

### Fixing the "pushing":

You are also fixing the list-item height, while your child `<a>` of your header list item has two lines, which make the `<a>` element go outside the bounding box you set.

Removing that height from this code:

```
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

(or making it min-height) will make it push the other list items down.

*Perhaps you are looking for `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to add some spacing to the entire element, rather than to each line?*

---

[Here's a total adjustment that makes use of the suggestions I just offered you](http://jsfiddle.net/u5w72jep/2/)

#### `margin-left:`

```
.sidebar-nav li {
    margin-left: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

---

#### `box-sizing`, `padding`, and not `line-height`:

```
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: initial;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's great. I made one little adjustment: I stuck with the original `text-indent` in the `.sidebar-nav li` as this makes the hover highlight the entire width of the sidebar; and in the `brand` child I put in `text-indent: initial; margin-left: 20px;`  . Seems to work great so far!

Comment: Update: although this looks great in Firefox, IE10 still has both of the same initial problems (it has a lot of space between the first and second line of the Brand )

Comment: Fixed IE10 problem by using `line-height: 100%;` for the brand. Not sure what is going on here as the w3schools documentation says that `line-height` is for specifying the gap between paragraphs, and I wouldn't have considered word-wrapped words as being a new paragraph